# Database not displaying info

Tags: asp.net

No errors but I'm not sure why my database is not displaying my info. Can anyone help?

Registration.cs

```
    protected void Reg_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string formUserNameID = username.ToString();
        string formEmailID = email.ToString();
        string formPasswordID = password.ToString();

        NotLoggedIn displayDataObj = new NotLoggedIn();
        displayDataObj.InsertRegName(formUserNameID, formEmailID, formPasswordID);
```

<------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
NotLoggedIn.cs

```
    public virtual void InsertRegName(string formUserNameID, string formEmailID, string formPasswordID)
    {
        TextBox userName = new TextBox();
        TextBox email = new TextBox();
        TextBox password = new TextBox();

        formUserNameID = userName.Text;
        formEmailID = email.Text;
        formPasswordID = password.Text;

        try
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString); //creates sql connection object  to the database via connection string 
            conn.Open(); //Open Connection
            string insertUserQuery = "insert into users (UserName,Email,Password) values (@Uname, @email, @password)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertUserQuery, conn); //COmmand that imputs query and allows connection
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", formUserNameID);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", formEmailID);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", formPasswordID);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Registration is successful.");

            conn.Close(); //Close Connection 

        }
        catch (Exception regEx)
        {
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error" + regEx.ToString());

        }

    }
```

Comment: Doing `Response.Write()` is not going to work well, as it writes directly to the response and you don't have any control over where the HTML ends up in the DOM. Instead, append data to a label. This could be masking your actual problem. Also, assuming `username`, `email` and `password` are text boxes, you should use their `.Text` property instead of calling `.ToString()` which will probably just give their type name.

Comment: Close connection immediately after command execution. Always better to write connection within using statement. InsertRegName function not using any input parameters data.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a little bit confused about the input parameters data. Any references online?